# Interview question - numbered tiles

Tags: puzzle

Ok, this interview question interested me and I would love to see an explanation!

There are some tiles: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3

They must be placed in a straight line, such that there is one tile between the 1s, two tiles between the 2s and three tiles between the 3s.

E.g. 312132

Now, you could add two 4s: 41312432

But it is impossible to add two 5s.

The question is how to prove this..

What would be the proof, and how would you derive it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Label the placement positions consecutively with the numbers $1, 2, ..., 10$.

Since the $1$-labeled tiles have to be placed one apart from each other, we can write their positions as $a$ and $a+2$ for some $1 \le a \le 8$.

Similarly, you can write the positions of the $2$-labeled tiles as $b$ and $b+3$ for some $1 \le b \le 7$.

Keeping up with the pattern, the $3$-labeled tiles are at $c$ and $c+4$, the $4$-labeled tiles are at $d$ and $d+5$, and the $5$-labeled tiles are at $e$ and $e+6$.

Now suppose you could successfully place all the pairs of tiles.  This means that each of the placement positions $\{1, 2, ..., 10\}$ is covered by exactly one of the values $\{a, a+2, b, b+3, c, c+4, d, d+5, e, e+6\}$.

So that means that the sum of the values $\{1, 2, ..., 10\}$ is the same as the sum of the values $\{a, a+2, b, b+3, c, c+4, d, d+5, e, e+6\}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum \{1, 2, ..., 10\} &= \sum \{a, a+2, b, b+3, c, c+4, d, d+5, e, e+6\} \\
55 &= 2a + 2b + 2c + 2d + 2e + 20 \\
&= 2(a+b+c+d+e) + 20
\end{align}
$$
which implies that
$$
2(a+b+c+d+e) = 35
$$
Since $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $e$ are integers, that's not possible.  So such a placement can't happen.

Answer (score 4):

With tiles labeled $1,1,2,2,\ldots, n,n$ you have to place these at positions $1,2,\ldots, 2n$ such that the positions of the two tiles with label $k$ differ by $k+1$. Hence if $k$ is even, these tiles occupy one odd and one even position, whereas for odd $k$, the pair occupies two positions of equal parity. Hence if $r$ of the odd tile pairs occupy even positions and $\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor-r$ pairs occupy odd positions, we need that these counts are equal, i.e. $\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor=2r$. For $n=5$, the left hand side is odd, hence no such $r$ exists. (It may work again for $n=7$).